# Why does angular show page greyed out?

Tags: angularjs, routes

I have an angular.js application, where I am trying to redirect usgin the following code:

```
this.openPresentationDetails = function (presentationToShow) {
    $location.path("/presentation");
};
```

It redirects to the proper page, however, the page appears greyed out. I have tried linking to other pages, and the result is the same.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: We will need more code about your Angular application. This question is incomplete

Comment: For changing or loading other views you should use $stateProvider or $routeProvider.

Answer (score 0):

I was invoking openPresentationDetails(...) from a modal form, I had to close the modal first and then redirect.